# How to recieve formdata in django backend

Tags: javascript, django, media

I want to send the recorded wecam video to django backend, But can't figure out how to generate the video in backend.

```
function sendVideoToAPI () {
    
const url = '/upload/' 
let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type });

let fd = new FormData();
let file = new File([blob], 'recording');

fd.append('data', file);

fetch(url1, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: fd
  })
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

In django views  how to generate the video
.Is there any way to do it..?

**EDIT**

*Views.py*

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       
        request.FILES.get('data') as f:
            print(f.size)
            print(type(f))

        return redirect("/")
```

while running server it gives The following error

**Error**

```
 request.FILES.get('data') as f:
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

in django's view you can access to your files through request like this:

```
request.FILES.get('data') as f:
    # your code
```

**NOTE**: this will make you a 'TemporaryUploadedFile' which means that after working with that, it destroys automatically

Comment: How to save the file in the directory ..??, How do i get the length of the video ..??

Comment: when you get the file, the file will be created in the temp directory (you can change it in settings.py)

Comment: While using   request.FILES.get('data') as f :. It gives me a syntax error